# Why do I get 'Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null' in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code, null, getelementbyid

I am learning JavaScript. While I have no problems with getting a result within the  Firefox browser when writing 'getElementById'and the appropriate code  in the html folder in vscode, when the same code is applied to the JSON folder, I get the 'Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null' message.  Firefox is not the problem, as the answer `105' is given in the console mode of'inspect' in Firefox, while coding the following code in the JSON file:

`var b = 'somename'; console.log(b); var someNumber = 105; console.log(someNumber);`

This proves that while the browser and the link between the html file and the JSON file in vscode are both working fine (which is indicated by the browser giving the answer as '105'), then there is a problem with vscode reading 'getElementById' correctly in the JSON file. Is this then a script loading problem with VSC reading the JSON file before the html file, thus resulting in it giving a 'null' value (which I don't know how to solve), or is this instead a legitmate bug? Or have I merely gotten the coding wrong in the JSON file, as this is the code which I have used, which is not working:

```
`document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Hi;`
```

While the answer 'Hi' is given when working in the html file, I instead get the error message in the JSON file.

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: Your writing JavaScript in a JSON file, that's not how things work. If it is working in your other scripts, then that's great, because you have working knowledge of perhaps the most fundamental JavaScript method for working with Document Object Models, (otherwise known as the D.O.M. pronounced as a word, rather than by its acronym form, "Dom"). JSON files are for storing data. To better understand how to use JSON, Check out this link https://www.impressivewebs.com/what-is-json-introduction-guide-for-beginners/

Comment: @KymJones if your Question is incorrect, you can, and should edit it Kym.

Comment: BTW I really like your dog, I have 3 :-). And way to go with your progress so far, IDK how long it took you to be able to have `getElementById` working properly, but some people are never able to get it working on their own, and have to have help. If this seems easy to you, you might have a knack for it.